# KDE distorted tooltips

Tags: 18.04, graphics, kubuntu, kde

I have Kububtu 18.04 and suddenly I found distortion in tooltips, for example, the quick launcher [ALT + Space] looks like below:
[image]

Also tooltips in other applications such as Firefox, Vivaldi looks like below:
[image]

``````
screenfetch
                          ./+o+-       saidbakr@Satellite-L850-A700
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-26-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 22m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 3467
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.20
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x900
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: KDE 5.47.0 / Plasma 5.12.9
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: KWin
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Card
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Tela-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Noto Sans Regular
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i5-2450M @ 4x 3.1GHz
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.3.0-26-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 1680MiB / 7921MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

I don't know what is up?

### Update:

I observed that OpenGL is the issue source. From *System Settings* **>** *Display and Monitor* **>** *Compositor* when I change **Rendering backend** to *XRender* from OpenGL 3.1 or OpenGL 2.0, the issue is gone away. Hence, now I need to know, **how to fix the OpenGL?**

```
glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.3.0-26-generic, LLVM 9.0.1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.0-devel (git-58ba7b6 2020-01-27 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.0.0-devel (git-58ba7b6 2020-01-27 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.0-devel (git-58ba7b6 2020-01-27 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

### Final Update:

**A system update** has been occurred today including some `mesa` stuff solves the issue. Now I use OpenGL 3.1 in the compositor settings without any problem. For my case, the issue is **closed**.

Comment: I had the same bug with another AMD GPU (Radeon HD 5700) in Ubuntu 19.10 (now fixed). So your bug is related with your AMD GPU. https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1841718

Comment: @JerareYoshi I have new update on the issue.

Comment: Maybe it's the ppa repo fault (with mesa) but i can't verify.

Comment: @JerareYoshi Finally it has been solved today. Thank you.