# cursor tooltip broken ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, tooltip

[Original image for Dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kopUd.png) 
[Original image for web application hinted element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX3EB.png)

In case of hovering cursor over an application icon on the Dock panel, or over hinted elements in browser, hint text is shown incorrectly.
Not only this image also many apps have these font alignment error. Please help
[image: Dock incorrect hint text]
[image: Browser hinted element picture]

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203975/kde-distorted-tooltips and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2435361. Seems to be an issue with your AMD GPU.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to change theme in:

**Main menu -> System Tools -> Budgie Themes**

Maybe it's a bug in a theme.

Second. Try to install and test another desktop manager.

The next suggested step is to upgrade to newer Ubuntu version with newer graphic packages and kernel. I've installed my system with 18.04, then upgraded it to 18.10, 19.04, 19.10. In my case I had no issues. But if you have manually installed proprietary video drivers or something similar, you could expect some issues, so be cautious.

Also, the comment by Jerare Yoshi from linked question says:

> I had the same bug with another AMD GPU (Radeon HD 5700) in Ubuntu
>   19.10 (now fixed). So your bug is related with your AMD GPU

This means you could also install fixed graphic drivers.

Comment: I am not using budgie themes and also this bug is even showing in webpages. link1

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all`