# Floating menu is broken

Tags: graphics

I ran apt update and upgrade last friday and after that most of the "floating menus" (I don't know the real name) are messed up.

Here are some images to illustrate:

[image: On the icon label]

[image: On the rigth click menu]

[image: On a select menu]

Please, can someone help me to fix it?

**Update:**

I really don't know what happened but it started to work and all I did was log off and on again.
I ran apt update and upgrade this morning again, maybe it fixed this bug.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: There was a similar question recently: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203975/kde-distorted-tooltips